# PHP not working on Apple OS X(10.10.3)

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

php -v returns 
PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2015 23:30:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

I had PHP working a few days ago.  Today I have not been able to get it to work.  I noticed in the httpd.conf file that the PHP module had been commented out.  I removed the # and restarted Apache and still nothing.  Apache seems to be running and MySQL also seems to be working fine.

1. What would have made changes to my httpd.conf file?
2. What can I do to get it working again?

Comment: In your apache configuration you have `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` ? or something similar?  Do you have the file handler for the extension? `<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>` in your configuration?
try running through the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using a package like MAMP; MAMP will overwrite the default configuration files with its own.
2. First, verify the LoadModule directive for PHP in the apache configuration is pointing to the correct path. Next, try to confirm Apache has loaded the PHP module:

   ```
   # apache2ctl –M
   ```
3. After you've verified Apache has loaded mod_php5, bring up your PHP file in a browser.  Check the file is named with the .php extension, and that this extension is associated with an Apache handler in your httpd.conf:

   ```
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
   ```
4. If you're still seeing nothing, check your Apache error log:

   ```
   # tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
   ```

Comment: 1.  I have MAMP installed but I don't think I am using it.  2.  The LoadModule directive for PHP is pointing to: libexec/apache2/libphp5.so .  It does seem the PHP module has been loaded.  The last line from that command you provided is: php5_module (shared)